# How is a message digest decrypted?

Tags: security

Trying to get my head around digital signatures and hit a slight block. The book I am using gives the following information

- Device A hashes a message to create a message digest
- Device A encrypts the digest with device A's private key to create a
  signature
- Device A adds the signature to the message
- Device A encrypts the whole message (including the signature) using device B's public key
- Device A sends the message to device B
- Device B decrypts the message with device B's private key
- Device B splits the signature off of the message
- Device B decrypts the signature using device A's public key to get
  the message digest
- Device B hashes the message to get a message digest
- If the message digest device B created is the same as the one
  decrpyted, the message has not been tampered with

All fine, but how does device B know what hashing algorithm was used to create the message digest?

Comment: This question is off topic here. You could consider asking this on [security.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com) or [cryptography.stackexchange.com](https://cryptography.stackexchange.com), but I suggest you read up on what's on topic there first.

Answer (score 1):

The hashing method needs to be configured the same on both sides. It could be manually configured, or it could be negotiated during the connection set up. It all depends on the systems and software involved.